# Contact form didn't work on hosting.

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, xampp

Got this one contact form ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/13884/)).
When testing on local machine with XAMPP it works fine. Got my messages in mailoutput.

On real hosting AJAX didn't work. Got message on email, but form isn't reset.

```
$(function() {

// Get the form.
var form = $('#contactForm');

// Get the messages div.
var formMessages = $('#form-messages');

// Set up an event listener for the contact form.
$(form).submit(function(e) {
    // Stop the browser from submitting the form.
    e.preventDefault();

    // Serialize the form data.
    var formData = $(form).serialize();

    // Submit the form using AJAX.
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $(form).attr('action'),
        data: formData
    })
    .done(function(response) {
        // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'success' class.
        $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
        $(formMessages).addClass('success');

        // Set the message text.
        $(formMessages).text(response);

        $('#button').text('SENT');
        $('#button').prop('disabled', true);

        // Clear the form.
        $('#name').val('');
        $('#email').val('');
        $('#message').val('');
    })
    .fail(function(data) {
        // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'error' class.
        $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
        $(formMessages).addClass('error');

        // Set the message text.
        if (data.responseText !== '') {
            //$(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
        } else {
            $(formMessages).text('Whoops!');
        }
    });

});
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

P.S.

How to fix this state, when you press the button? 
Color is out of bounds.
[image]